# Leetcode Longest Common Prefix runtime error

Tags: python

Here's the original question: 
https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/

I was able to pass basic test, but when submitting online always got a runtime error. Also, can't pass the test when input is [""].

---

```
class Solution(object):
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs):
        """
        :type strs: List[str]
        :rtype: str
        """
        def pf(x):
            def first(i):
                if len(i)>0:
                    return i[0]
                else: 
                    return ""
            def rest(i):
                if len(i)>1:
                    return i[1:]
                else: 
                    return ""

            first_list = map(first,x)
            compare = len(set(first_list)) ## are all the letter the same

            if compare != 1:
                return []
            else:
                # print "~~~~~~", map(first,x)[0]
                r = map(first,x) + pf(map(rest,x))
                return r


        temp= pf(strs)
        return "".join(list(set(temp)))
```

Comment: If you have strings of different lengths it's possible to get an index error with this code when you try `i[0]` on an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking if you've run out of characters, and `""[0]` throws an index error. You're also calling `"".join(list(set(temp)))` which has logical problems that you'll discover.

Here's a very pythonic solution.

```
def longest_prefix(strs):
  prefix = []

  for chars in zip(*strs):
    print chars
    if len(set(chars)) == 1:
      prefix.append(chars[0])
    else:
      break

  return "".join(prefix)

print "prefix=", longest_prefix(["flower","flow","flight"])
print "prefix=", longest_prefix(["flower","flow","float"])
print "prefix=", longest_prefix([""])
prefix= ('f', 'f', 'f')
('l', 'l', 'l')
('o', 'o', 'i')
fl
prefix= ('f', 'f', 'f')
('l', 'l', 'l')
('o', 'o', 'o')
('w', 'w', 'a')
flo
prefix=
```

Comment: could you explain what kind of logical error i might encounter with join method?

Comment: @sopia - consider the order of operations. Join will join whatever the input is, so make sure what it receives is correct and in order.

Comment: thanks! that was a much elegant way of coding the same algorithm

Comment: on the other hand, the runtime is not very good. is it because of Zip? how would write it if not using build-in zip? thanks!